# Android XML folding /unfolding - Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I hope, I am not the only one who is facing the issue of not able to fold the Android XML components, layouts etc., I do find the option to Expanding, Collapsing Folding. But I do not see anything coming up once the option is selected. But occasionally I have seen the +,- BUttons for folding.

can anyone help me to resovle this issue or any possible workaroudn for this ?

There are few questions asked earlier, But there is not enough information on this. 
Old Question with no response:
[Folding button in android common xml editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922344/folding-button-in-android-common-xml-editor)

Comment: One bug reported Fixed. But Can anyone share some light on this ? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=269600

Comment: How was it fixed? I don't see it working...

Comment: Yeah. It doesn't work for me to. But I found a small workaround to help me out. When you are in the Xml editor, press Ctrl+ o . This will popup the outline view. Eventhough it doesn't solve the whole purpose, it is the best I found.